# Accessing only part of a list in Scala using .last

Tags: scala, collections

I have the following code which

```
val result = hyp().filter(_._3)
```

where hyp() returns List[(Int,Int,Set[Int])] and filter is used to return only those Lists where the set contains single element. _._3 accesses the Set(Int) part. How can I use .last instead of _._3? Thanks

Comment: do you mean `List[(Int,Int,Set[Int])]`? There is no *beautiful* way to swap _._3 with .last, but probably pattern matching is fine for you?

Comment: yes that is what I meant. How is it done with pattern matching?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to make this *beautiful* (note that I'm using version 1.2.4):

```
  import shapeless.Tuples._
  val result = hyp().filter(_.hlisted.last.size == 1)
```

Comment: This is even nicer with Shapeless 2.0 and the `Last` typeclass; no need to explicitly convert to an HList :)

Comment: @BenJames I want Shapeless 2.0, but I'm waiting for it to be out of milestone phase and into release phase

Comment: Absolutely understandable! I just wanted to mention it in a comment, rather than write another version of this answer with Shapeless 2.

Answer (score 3):

With pattern matching it might look like

```
val result = hyp().filter {
  case (_, _, x) => x.size == 1
}
```

Comment: The second `case` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the @kompot answer

```
val result = hyp().collect {
  case t @ (_, _, xs) if xs.size == 1 => t
}
```

Here I bind whole tuple to the `t` variable and if last tuple item has single element I pass it to the resulting collection